# How can I grant permission to my Linked Server user to see a list of stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server-2016, linked-server

I have a pair of SQL servers in two different domains.  One needs to get data from the other so I've configured a Linked Server object, configured with a Sql Server remote login and password defined on the target server.  On the target server, I have GRANTed EXECUTE ON several stored procedures and I can run them from the source server but only if I can remember their names!  It would make things easier if I could see them in the SSMS UI but I  can't. See the image below.

How can I make the Stored Procedures visible in the UI?  Ideally, I just want to see the ones that the Linked Server user can execute.

[image: Linked Server showing Tables and Views but no Stored Procedures]